# Coverity Point and Scan connectivity issue

Tags: coverity

I'm trying to scan test project with Synopsys Coverity Point and Scan tool v2022.12.2 for Windows 10. However, connection to the server take really long time. Switching project name takes long time. Sometimes I can scan, but I never been able to commit results.

Example: I click "Commit", then very lonng pause with message "Loading Streams..." then time out.

After some re-tris I see that there new streams are getting created at the server, which tells me that some small chunks of data coming through.

Error 1: Coverity Connect Instance is taking too long to reply

Error 2: Commit to Connect server failed: Please check if the server URL is correct and server is reachable.
I work through VPN. All other app download/upload data fast.
Another developer have same issue.
I'm able to connect to server web interface with no issues. Other team, allegedly, able to do the same with no problems.
How to solve?

[image: attempt to scan]

[image: attempt to commit]